# How can i update dynamic textbox values into database table on same ID using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

How can i update dynamic textbox values into database table on same ID using php?i hvae two table one is user and other is user family` $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

```
            $itemCount = count($_POST["familyname"]);
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $size) { 
                $familyname = $_POST['familyname'][$i];
                $frelationsh = $_POST['frelationsh'][$i];
                $fieldtype = $_POST['fieldtype'][$i]; 
                $pid = $_POST['pid'][$i];
                $update="UPDATE familydata SET familyname='$familyname', frelationsh='$frelationsh', fgender='$fgender', ''fbirthn='$fbirthn' WHERE pid='$pid'";
              
            }
                    
                print_r($update);
                exit();
```

Comment: You're missing an actual query for the update: mysqli_query($conn, $update); inside the while-loop. And the print_r() at the end is pointless.

Comment: Apart from your question you should not use mysqli. use PDO instead and send parameters through PDO. Your query is open for sql injections.

Comment: @StanMayan MySQLi is fine, using `mysql_*` functions not so much, since they're deprecated/have been removed.

Comment: @brombeer https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-vs-mysqli

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @StanMayan Yes, as I said, MySQLi is fine